# pandas multiprocessing apply

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use multiprocessing with pandas dataframe, that is split the dataframe to 8 parts. apply some function to each part using apply (with each part processed in different process).

EDIT:
Here's the solution I finally found:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas.util.testing as pdt

def process_apply(x):
    # do some stuff to data here

def process(df):
    res = df.apply(process_apply, axis=1)
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = mp.Pool(processes=8)
    split_dfs = np.array_split(big_df,8)
    pool_results = p.map(aoi_proc, split_dfs)
    p.close()
    p.join()

    # merging parts processed by different processes
    parts = pd.concat(pool_results, axis=0)

    # merging newly calculated parts to big_df
    big_df = pd.concat([big_df, parts], axis=1)

    # checking if the dfs were merged correctly
    pdt.assert_series_equal(parts['id'], big_df['id'])
```

Comment: @yemu what are you exactly trying to achieve by this code?

Comment: currently apply only saturates one core of the CPU. I want to use multiprocess and use all cores to decrease processing time

Comment: It would be nicer if you left the question alone and then put the answers in the answers. That way we can see more of the process without looking at the changelog.

Comment: should "aoi_proc" be "process"? Maybe renaming your "process" function to simply "f" would be more readable in the multiprocessing context

Comment: I'm puzzled as to what process_apply should look like. Mine is a function a function of the row. Something like: `def process_apply(rw): return(rw['A']*rw['B'])`. Is that correct?

Comment: You could look into Polars which is like pandas but with built-in automatic parallel processing. [Benchmarks](https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/) can be 3x as fast as pandas.

Answer (score 159):

You can use https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel, as in the following example:

```
from pandarallel import pandarallel
from math import sin

pandarallel.initialize()

def func(x):
    return sin(x**2)

df.parallel_apply(func, axis=1)
```

Comment: This answer should get more upvotes. The speed up is terrific.

Comment: This solution works on linux &macOS natively. On Windows, Pandaral·lel will works only if the Python session is executed from [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

Comment: On windows, I get this error: `ValueError: cannot find context for 'fork'`

Comment: if you are using `pandarallel` with `PyCharm`, you can disable `Run with Python Console`

Answer (score 58):

A more generic version based on the author solution, that allows to run it on every function and dataframe:

```
from multiprocessing import  Pool
from functools import partial
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def parallelize(data, func, num_of_processes=8):
    data_split = np.array_split(data, num_of_processes)
    pool = Pool(num_of_processes)
    data = pd.concat(pool.map(func, data_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return data

def run_on_subset(func, data_subset):
    return data_subset.apply(func, axis=1)

def parallelize_on_rows(data, func, num_of_processes=8):
    return parallelize(data, partial(run_on_subset, func), num_of_processes)
```

So the following line:

```
df.apply(some_func, axis=1)
```

Will become:

```
parallelize_on_rows(df, some_func)
```

Comment: What about `some_func` with parameters?

Comment: @AlaaM. - you can use partial for that.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Comment: @TomRaz how do I use a partial in this case when normally I would do something like this? `dataframe.apply(lambda row: process(row.attr1, row.attr2, ...))`

Comment: @frei - lambda functions cannot be used with multiprocessing, since they cannot be pickled. See more info here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8805244/1781490

Can you use normal functions instead?

Comment: i see ok. that's the piece i needed to know whether i should just refactor the whole method or not

Comment: @Tom Raz what if I don't use partial? What is the utility of using partial here?

Comment: when I do this the numpy splits gets processed twice, any idea why this may be happening to me?

Comment: great solution, just remember to not use lambda functions and to be careful with shadow variables. thanks

Answer (score 9):

This is some code that I found useful. Automatically splits the dataframe into however many cpu cores you have.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

def parallelize_dataframe(df, func):
    num_processes = mp.cpu_count()
    df_split = np.array_split(df, num_processes)
    with mp.Pool(num_processes) as p:
        df = pd.concat(p.map(func, df_split))
    return df

def parallelize_function(df):
    df[column_output] = df[column_input].apply(example_function)
    return df

def example_function(x):
    x = x*2
    return x
```

To run:

```
df_output = parallelize_dataframe(df, parallelize_function)
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked well for me:

```
rows_iter = (row for _, row in df.iterrows())

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    df['new_column'] = pool.map(process_apply, rows_iter)
```

Comment: @Robert Handzel's solution is faster though

Answer (score 4):

Since I don't have much of your data script, this is a guess, but I'd suggest using `p.map` instead of `apply_async` with the callback.

```
p = mp.Pool(8)
pool_results = p.map(process, np.array_split(big_df,8))
p.close()
p.join()
results = []
for result in pool_results:
    results.extend(result)
```

Comment: I had to put the call inside if __name__ == '__main__'. and with other small changes I managed to make it work, however I'm not sure if the result dataframes in pool results are returned in the same order as they were split. I have to check it.

Comment: see here for a solution with `dask` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979167/how-to-parallelize-many-fuzzy-string-comparisons-using-apply-in-pandas

Answer (score 2):

To use all (physical or logical) cores, you could try [`mapply`](https://pypi.org/project/mapply/) as an alternative to [`swifter`](https://pypi.org/project/swifter/) and [`pandarallel`](https://pypi.org/project/pandarallel/).

You can set the amount of cores (and the chunking behaviour) upon init:

```py
import pandas as pd
import mapply

mapply.init(n_workers=-1)

def process_apply(x):
    # do some stuff to data here

def process(df):
    # spawns a pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessPool if sensible
    res = df.mapply(process_apply, axis=1)
    return res
```

By default (`n_workers=-1`), the package uses all physical CPUs available on the system. If your system uses hyper-threading (usually twice the amount of physical CPUs would show up), `mapply` will spawn one extra worker to prioritise the multiprocessing pool over other processes on the system.

You could also use all logical cores instead (beware that like this the CPU-bound processes will be fighting for physical CPUs, which might slow down your operation):

```py
import multiprocessing
n_workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

# or more explicit
import psutil
n_workers = psutil.cpu_count(logical=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's [pool.starmap() method](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) can be used to succinctly introduce parallelism also to `apply` use cases where column values are passed as arguments, i.e. to cases like:

```py
df.apply(lambda row: my_func(row["col_1"], row["col_2"], ...), axis=1)
```

Full example and benchmarking:

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def mul(a, b, c):
    # For illustration, could obviously be vectorized
    return a * b * c

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10_000_000, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

# Standard apply
start = time.time()
df["mul"] = df.apply(lambda row: mul(row["A"], row["B"], row["C"]), axis=1)
print(f"Standard apply took {time.time() - start:.0f} seconds.") 

# Starmap apply
start = time.time()
with Pool(10) as pool:
    df["mul_pool"] = pool.starmap(mul, zip(df["A"], df["B"], df["C"]))
print(f"Starmap apply took {time.time() - start:.0f} seconds.") 

pd.testing.assert_series_equal(df["mul"], df["mul_pool"], check_names=False)


>>> Standard apply took 72 seconds.
>>> Starmap apply took 5 seconds.
```

This has the benefit of not relying on external libraries, plus being very readable.

Answer (score 0):

I also run into the same problem when I use `multiprocessing.map()` to apply function to different chunk of a large dataframe.

I just want to add several points just in case other people run into the same problem as I do.

1. remember to add `if __name__ == '__main__':`
2. execute the file in a `.py` file, if you use `ipython/jupyter notebook`, then you can not run `multiprocessing` (this is true for my case, though I have no clue)

Answer (score 0):

Install [Pyxtension](https://pypi.org/project/pyxtension/) that simplifies using parallel map and use like this:

```py
from pyxtension.streams import stream

big_df = pd.concat(stream(np.array_split(df, multiprocessing.cpu_count())).mpmap(process))
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map` in place of `multiprocessing.Pool.map` which took 316 microseconds for some code that took 12 seconds in serial.

Answer (score 0):

Tom Raz's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53135031/11847090 misses an edge case where there are fewer rows in the dataframe than processes

use this parallelize method instead

```
def parallelize(data, func, num_of_processes=8):
   # check if the number of rows is less than the number of processes
   # to avoid the following error
   # ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape
   num_rows = len(data)
    if num_rows == 0:
        return None
    elif num_rows < num_of_processes:
        num_of_processes = num_rows
    data_split = np.array_split(data, num_of_processes)
    pool = Pool(num_of_processes)
    data = pd.concat(pool.map(func, data_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return data
```

and also I used dask bag to multithread this instead of this custom code