# Parallel and conditional: NoneType object has no attribute '__dict__'

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

For more setup, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30741061/parallel-python-iteration/30745634?noredirect=1#comment49589964_30745634). I want to create lots of instances of class `Toy`, in parallel. Then I want to write them to an xml tree.

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import lxml.etree as et
import numpy as np
import sys
import multiprocessing as mp


def make_toys(df):
    l = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        toys = [Toy(row) for _ in range(row['number'])]
        l += [x for x in toys if x is not None]
    return l


class Toy(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if np.random.uniform() <= 1:
            return super(Toy, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, row):
        self.id = None
        self.type = row['type']

    def set_id(self, x):
        self.id = x

    def write(self, tree):
        et.SubElement(tree, "toy", attrib={'id': str(self.id), 'type': self.type})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    table = pd.DataFrame({
        'type': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        'number': [5, 4, 3, 10]})

    n_cores = 2
    split_df = np.array_split(table, n_cores)

    p = mp.Pool(n_cores)
    pool_results = p.map(make_toys, split_df)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    l = [a for L in pool_results for a in L]

    box = et.Element("box")
    box_file = et.ElementTree(box)

    for i, toy in itertools.izip(range(len(l)), l):
        Toy.set_id(toy, i)

    [Toy.write(x, box) for x in l]

    box_file.write(sys.stdout, pretty_print=True)
```

This code runs beautifully. But I redefined the `__new__` method to only have a random chance of instantiating a class. So if I set `if np.random.uniform() < 0.5`, I want to create half as many instances as I asked for, randomly determined. Doing this returns the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 380, in _handle_results
    task = get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

I don't know what this even means, or how to avoid it. If I do this process monolithically, as in `l = make_toys(table)`, it runs well for any random chance.

#### Another solution

By the way, I know that this can be solved by leaving the `__new__` method alone and instead rewriting `make_toys()` as

```
def make_toys(df):
    l = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        prob = np.random.binomial(row['number'], 0.1)
        toys = [Toy(row) for _ in range(prob)]
        l += [x for x in toys if x is not None]
    return l
```

But I'm trying to learn about the error.

Comment: I don't know what happened to the previous answer, but note that I am removing the `None` elements from the list of objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've uncovered a surprising "gotcha"  caused by `Toy`
instances becoming `None` as they are passed through the multiprocessing Pool's
result `Queue`.

The `multiprocessing.Pool` uses `Queue.Queue`s  to pass results from the subprocesses back to the main process.

[Per the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues):

> When an object is put on a queue, the object is pickled and a background
>     thread later flushes the pickled data to an underlying pipe.

While the actual serialization might be different, in spirit
the pickling of an instance of `Toy` becomes a stream of bytes such as this:

```
In [30]: import pickle

In [31]: pickle.dumps(Toy(table.iloc[0]))
Out[31]: "ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\np0\n(c__main__\nToy\np1\nc__builtin__\nobject\np2\nNtp3\nRp4\n(dp5\nS'type'\np6\nS'a'\np7\nsS'id'\np8\nNsb."
```

Notice that the module and class of the object is mentioned in the stream of
bytes: `__main__\nToy`.

*The class itself is not pickled*. There is only a reference to the name of the class.

When the stream of bytes is unpickled on the other side of the pipe, **`Toy.__new__` is called** to instantiate a new instance of `Toy`. The new object's `__dict__` is then reconstituted using unpickled data from the byte stream. When the new object is `None`, it has no `__dict__` attribute, and hence the AttributeError is raised.

Thus, as a `Toy` instance is passed through the `Queue`, it might become `None` on the other side.

I believe this is the reason why using

```
class Toy(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        x = np.random.uniform() <= 0.5
        if x:
            return super(Toy, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        logger.info('Returning None')
```

leads to

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

---

If you add logging to your script,

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import lxml.etree as et
import numpy as np
import sys
import multiprocessing as mp
import logging
logger = mp.log_to_stderr(logging.INFO)

def make_toys(df):
    result = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        toys = [Toy(row) for _ in range(row['number'])]
        result += [x for x in toys if x is not None]
    return result


class Toy(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        x = np.random.uniform() <= 0.97
        if x:
            return super(Toy, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        logger.info('Returning None')

    def __init__(self, row):
        self.id = None
        self.type = row['type']

    def set_id(self, x):
        self.id = x

    def write(self, tree):
        et.SubElement(tree, "toy", attrib={'id': str(self.id), 'type': self.type})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    table = pd.DataFrame({
        'type': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        'number': [5, 4, 3, 10]})

    n_cores = 2
    split_df = np.array_split(table, n_cores)

    p = mp.Pool(n_cores)
    pool_results = p.map(make_toys, split_df)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    l = [a for L in pool_results for a in L]

    box = et.Element("box")
    box_file = et.ElementTree(box)

    for i, toy in itertools.izip(range(len(l)), l):
        toy.set_id(i)

    for x in l:
        x.write(box)

    box_file.write(sys.stdout, pretty_print=True)
```

you will find that the `AttributeError` only
occurs after a logging message of the form

```
[INFO/MainProcess] Returning None
```

Notice that the logging message comes from the MainProcess, not one of the
PoolWorker processes. Since the `Returning None` message comes from
`Toy.__new__`, this shows that `Toy.__new__` was called by the main process.
This corroborates the claim that unpickling is calling
`Toy.__new__` and transforming instances of `Toy` into `None`.

---

The moral of the story is that for `Toy` instances to be passed through a multiprocessing Pool's Queue,  `Toy.__new__` must always return an instance of
`Toy`. And as you noted, the code can be fixed by instantiating only the desired number of Toys in `make_toys`:

```
def make_toys(df):
    result = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        prob = np.random.binomial(row['number'], 0.1)
        result.extend([Toy(row) for _ in range(prob)])
    return result
```

---

By the way, it is non-standard to call instance methods with `Toy.write(x, box)`
when `x` is an instance of `Toy`. The preferred way is to use

```
x.write(box)
```

Similary, use `toy.set_id(i)` instead of `Toy.set_id(toy, i)`.

Comment: Thanks for the style tips; I'm pretty new to Python. But I thought that the line `[x for x in toys if x is not None]` removed those non-objects.

Comment: Also, moving the chance to the `for` loop would be suboptimal, especially because `__init__` in my actual code does quite a bit. I'd rather not go through all that if I'm just going to throw the object away.

Comment: Oh dear, I missed that. The Nones must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: I think you've uncovered a surprising "gotcha" which is caused by some  `Toy` instances becoming `None` as they are passed through the multiprocessing Pool's result Queue.