# how to parallelize many (fuzzy) string comparisons using apply in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, dask, fuzzywuzzy

I have the following problem

I have a dataframe **master** that contains sentences, such as

```
master
Out[8]: 
                  original
0  this is a nice sentence
1      this is another one
2    stackoverflow is nice
```

For every row in Master, I lookup into another Dataframe **slave** for the best match using `fuzzywuzzy`. I use fuzzywuzzy because the matched sentences between the two dataframes could differ a bit (extra characters, etc).

For instance, **slave** could be

```
slave
Out[10]: 
   my_value                      name
0         2               hello world
1         1           congratulations
2         2  this is a nice sentence 
3         3       this is another one
4         1     stackoverflow is nice
```

Here is a fully-functional, wonderful, compact working example :)

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import difflib


master= pd.DataFrame({'original':['this is a nice sentence',
'this is another one',
'stackoverflow is nice']})


slave= pd.DataFrame({'name':['hello world',
'congratulations',
'this is a nice sentence ',
'this is another one',
'stackoverflow is nice'],'my_value': [2,1,2,3,1]})

def fuzzy_score(str1, str2):
    return fuzz.token_set_ratio(str1, str2)

def helper(orig_string, slave_df):
    #use fuzzywuzzy to see how close original and name are
    slave_df['score'] = slave_df.name.apply(lambda x: fuzzy_score(x,orig_string))
    #return my_value corresponding to the highest score
    return slave_df.ix[slave_df.score.idxmax(),'my_value']

master['my_value'] = master.original.apply(lambda x: helper(x,slave))
```

**The 1 million dollars question is: can I parallelize my apply code above?**

After all, every row in `master` is compared to all the rows in `slave` (slave is a small dataset and I can hold many copies of the data into the RAM).

I dont see why I could not run multiple comparisons (i.e. process multiple rows at the same time).

Problem: I dont know how to do that or if thats even possible.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I notice you added the dask tag here.  Have you tried using dask already and run into an issue?

Comment: thanks for your help! it seems dask only accepts regular functions

Comment: also, I only have one computer so no distributed jobs across machines

Comment: Dask uses cloudpickle to serialize functions and so can easily handle lambdas and closures over other datasets.

Comment: then would you be able to write the simple code above in dask, as you suggest?

Comment: About the same, but I would use `assign` rather than column assignment and I would provide metadata to `apply` about the column you expect.  If you create a minimal reproducible example then it'll be easier to provide an explicit solution.  For example, something that I can copy-and-paste to just work on my local machine.

Comment: thats sounds good. i believe the code above is fully functional

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115351/discussion-between-mrocklin-and-noobie).

Comment: cannot use the chat right now unfortunately. please tell me whatever you need and i will do my very best! thanks for your help

Comment: ok got it let me create a paste and go code for you

Comment: hello @MRocklin, please see my updated answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can parallelize this with Dask.dataframe.

```
>>> dmaster = dd.from_pandas(master, npartitions=4)
>>> dmaster['my_value'] = dmaster.original.apply(lambda x: helper(x, slave), name='my_value'))
>>> dmaster.compute()
                  original  my_value
0  this is a nice sentence         2
1      this is another one         3
2    stackoverflow is nice         1
```

Additionally, you should think about the tradeoffs between using threads vs processes here.  Your fuzzy string matching almost certainly doesn't release the GIL, so you won't get any benefit from using multiple threads.  However, using processes will cause data to serialize and move around your machine, which might slow things down a bit.

You can experiment between using threads and processes or a distributed system by managing the `get=` keyword argument to the `compute()` method.

```
import dask.multiprocessing
import dask.threaded

>>> dmaster.compute(get=dask.threaded.get)  # this is default for dask.dataframe
>>> dmaster.compute(get=dask.multiprocessing.get)  # try processes instead
```

Comment: genius! just a quick question: I have a 8 core xeon machine, will that work on it? I cannot use a distributed system as you suggest

Comment: Multiprocessing will accelerate your computations but will slow down from inter-process data transfer.  There's no way for me to know if things will speed up or not without knowing way more about your problem than I really want to get into.  I recommend trying it out and profiling.

Comment: thanks @MRocklin ! I am sure many will find this post useful. I, myself, was still completely clueless about `dask` after skimming through http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/install.html

Comment: follow up if you still have 20 secs. should I play with `npartitions` as well?

Comment: I have a lot of RAM (128GB), so should I use many npartitions?

Comment: sorry for the follow up, but maybe you can give me a hint? I see now a lot of processes running for quite a long time, but the CPU usage remains very low with some spikes at 2% - 5% every few seconds or so. Is this expected? Thank you again for your time

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on something similar and I wanted to provide a more complete working solution for anyone else you might stumble upon this question. @MRocklin unfortunately has some syntax errors in the code snippets provided. I am no expert with Dask, so I can't comment on some performance considerations, but this should accomplish your task just as @MRocklin has suggested.  This is using **Dask version 0.17.2** and **Pandas version 0.22.0**:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.multiprocessing
import dask.threaded
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pandas as pd

master= pd.DataFrame({'original':['this is a nice sentence',
'this is another one',
'stackoverflow is nice']})

slave= pd.DataFrame({'name':['hello world',
'congratulations',
'this is a nice sentence ',
'this is another one',
'stackoverflow is nice'],'my_value': [1,2,3,4,5]})

def fuzzy_score(str1, str2):
    return fuzz.token_set_ratio(str1, str2)

def helper(orig_string, slave_df):
    slave_df['score'] = slave_df.name.apply(lambda x: fuzzy_score(x,orig_string))
    #return my_value corresponding to the highest score
    return slave_df.loc[slave_df.score.idxmax(),'my_value']

dmaster = dd.from_pandas(master, npartitions=4)
dmaster['my_value'] = dmaster.original.apply(lambda x: helper(x, slave),meta=('x','f8'))
```

Then, obtain your results (like in this interpreter session):

```
In [6]: dmaster.compute(get=dask.multiprocessing.get)                                             
Out[6]:                                          
                  original  my_value             
0  this is a nice sentence         3             
1      this is another one         4             
2    stackoverflow is nice         5
```

Answer (score 2):

These answers are based on an older API. Some newer code:

```
dmaster = dd.from_pandas(master, npartitions=4)
dmaster['my_value'] = dmaster.original.apply(lambda x: helper(x, slave),meta=('x','f8'))
dmaster.compute(scheduler='processes')
```

Personally I'd ditch that apply call to fuzzy_score in the helper function and just perform the operation there.

You can alter the scheduler using [these tips](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduler-overview.html).