# Why is conversion of Dask dataframe to pandas dataframe really slow?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I'm getting pandas dataframe from dask using

```
p_df_data=d_df_data.compute()
```

But this is really slow...
Is there an alternative method?

Comment: This really depends on what transformations you are applying. Related: [why is multiprocessing slower than a simple computation in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837539/why-is-multiprocessing-slower-than-a-simple-computation-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dask dataframes are lazy, all operations are free until you call compute, at which point they all occur.