# Is it possible to get the PID of the sibling process by using `psutil` or any other Python packages?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I am running a set of [parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57820724/10449636) computing.

I am trying to use `psutil` to track the computation (If someone has a better solution, plz tell me)

```
>>> p = psutil.Process(4370)
>>> p.cpu_percent()
0.0
>>> p.cpu_times()
pcputimes(user=6440.78, system=5.4, children_user=0.0, children_system=0.0)
>>> p.cpu_affinity()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> p.cpu_num()
2
```

I guess the last one get a value of 2 for `p.cpu_num()` indicates that this job is on parallel computing, there is another sibling process doing the computing simultaneously.

Is it possible to get the PID of the sibling process by using `psutil` or any other Python packages?

Comment: did you try to get `.parent()` and later use `.process_iter()` to get all procces and check which one has the same parent ?

Comment: simply track the computation within the computation itself, not outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*I guess the last one get **a value of `2` for `p.cpu_num()` indicates that this job is on parallel** computing*"

No, this does not mean anything other but that a process `p` is currently mapped onto the second CPU from all CPU-s available ( O/S task scheduler decides on which CPU/core a job is going to get executed + the process-affinity settings may restrict such a choice )

```
>>> print( p.cpu_num.__doc__ )
Return what CPU this process is currently running on.
            The returned number should be <= psutil.cpu_count()
            and <= len(psutil.cpu_percent(percpu=True)).
            It may be used in conjunction with
            psutil.cpu_percent(percpu=True) to observe the system
            workload distributed across CPUs.
```

> **Q** : *Is it possible to get the PID of the sibling process by using `psutil`*

Yes, it is. How? It is quite enough to follow the documentation to assemble any traversing tree strategy that meets your needs and expectations upto a system-level universal process-monitor.

```
>>> aParentOfThisPROCESS = psutil.Process( thisProcess.parent().pid )
>>> aParentOfThisPROCESS.threads()
6
>>> aParentOfThisPROCESS.open_files()
[popenfile(path='/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', fd=8, position=0, mode='r', flags=32768)]

>>> print( aParentOfThisPROCESS.children.__doc__ )
Return the children of this process as a list of Process
        instances, pre-emptively checking whether PID has been reused.
        If *recursive* is True return all the parent descendants.

        Example (A == this process):

         A ─┐
            │
            ├─ B (child) ─┐
            │             └─ X (grandchild) ─┐
            │                                └─ Y (great grandchild)
            ├─ C (child)
            └─ D (child)

        >>> import psutil
        >>> p = psutil.Process()
        >>> p.children()
        B, C, D
        >>> p.children(recursive=True)
        B, X, Y, C, D

        Note that in the example above if process X disappears
        process Y won't be listed as the reference to process A
        is lost.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "a process p is currently mapped onto the second CPU", is the O/S task scheduler a part of Python or Operating System?

Comment: O/S is an abbreviation of **O**perating **S**ystem. O/S is a system, that supervises how the hardware is being used, operates the task scheduler (which process/thread gets a permit to load onto real CPU and have some amount of time to get executed a part of the code, before it gets signaled and been evicted from CPU to a rear-side of the task-scheduler queue, and some other process/thread gets loaded in that place ). This is how O/S-es work. Even if any application ( be it python, web-browser, whatever ) asks for 120-threads, the O/S scheduler decides what/when/where/for how long gets exec'd

Comment: Consider this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57865808/10449636),  running parallel on Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.7.3, numpy 1.16.4, sklearn 0.21.2, is there another intermediate scheduler/wrapper between the task and OS scheduler, such something in joblib package or any other Python parallel package?