# Dask parallelize a short task that uses a large np.ndarray

Tags: python, multiprocessing, dask

I have a function `f` that uses as input a variable `x` which is a *large* `np.ndarray` (lenght 20000).
Execution of `f` takes very little (about 5ms).

A `for` loop over a matrix `M` with many rows

```
for x in M:
    f(x)
```

takes about 5 times longer than parallelizing using multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(f, M)
```

I have tried to parallelize with dask but it loses even against sequential execution. Related post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57820724/why-does-dask-perform-so-slower-while-multiprocessing-perform-so-much-faster#:%7E:text=In%20your%20example%2C%20dask%20is,the%20task%20graph%20in%20parallel.) but the accepted answer doesn´t work for me. I have tried many thing like use partitions of the data as the [best practices](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/delayed-best-practices.html) say or using `dask.bag`. I'm running Dask in local machine with 4 physical cores.

So the question is **how to use dask with short tasks that take large data as input?**

Comment: you say you tried Dask, but don't show your attempt! additionally, what operating system are you using? (Windows systems often cannot effectively use `multiprocessing`)

Comment: I am building a reproducible example

Comment: The answer will depend on the process creation https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods . I assume your multiprocessing is using fork and dask is using forkserver.

Comment: based on the description of "short task" I would say don't use Multiprocessing. Use `numba` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the dask documentation makes clear the following contraindications:

- it is a bad idea to create big data in the client and pass it to workers; you should have workers load the data they need
- if the data you need fit into memory, the standard python tool (in this case numpy) probably works as well or better than dask
- if you want to share memory and are running processes such as numpy that release the GIL, then you should prefer threads over processes.
- dask multiprocessing should not generally be used if you can run distributed (i.e., always)
- don't use a python loop over an array, you should vectorize

Since we don't know much about what you are doing or your system, I will provide a guess of why dask is slower than multiprocessing. When you use multiprocessing.pool, probably the system created processes via `fork`, and copied (or copy-on-write duplicated) the array into each process, so they can access it. Dask requires threads and event loops to run, so it is not safe to use with `fork`. This means, that when you want data in the client to be processed in a worker, it must be serialised and sent over IPC. This is very likely the cause of your slowdown.