# How to speed up / replace a python for loop

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I am running the following code:

```
def get_previous_next_returns(portfolio,total_returns):
    assets=[]
    i=0
    for asset in portfolio:
        i+=1
        try:
            for offset in [1,5,15,30,45,60,75,90,120,150,
                           200,250,500,750,1000,1250,1500]:
                print(i,asset.name,offset)
                asset['return_stock'] = (asset.Close - asset.Close.shift(1)) / (asset.Close.shift(1))
                merged_data = pd.merge(asset, sp_500, on='Date')
                total_positive_days=0
                total_beating_sp_days=0
                total_days = offset
                for index in range(0,len(merged_data)):
                    if index-offset>0:
                #for index, row in merged_data.iterrows():
                    #print(offset, index)
                        sliced = merged_data.iloc[index - offset : index]
                        total_positive_days = (sliced.Close_x > sliced.Close_x.shift(1)).sum()
                        total_beating_sp_days = (sliced.return_stock > sliced.return_sp).sum()
                        percentage_of_positive_days = float(total_positive_days/total_days)
                        percentage_of_beating_days = float(total_beating_sp_days/total_days)
                        asset.loc[index,'Pct_positive_'+str(offset)] = percentage_of_positive_days
                        asset.loc[index,'Pct_beating_'+str(offset)] = percentage_of_beating_days
                # previous period returns
                asset['Pct_change_'+str(offset)] = asset['Close'].pct_change(periods = offset)
                # next period returns
                asset['Pct_change_plus_'+str(offset)] = asset['Close'].pct_change(periods = -offset)
            assets.append(asset)
            total_returns=total_returns.append(asset) 
        except IndexError:
            print("Index error")
    return assets, total_returns
```

The problem is the dataframe I am running it on (merged_data) is very large (over 1 million rows) thus the code takes many hours to complete... Is there a way to somehow speed it up (i.e. replacign the for loop with a more efficient code block?

Comment: You could split your dataframe into different chuncks and use `multiprocessing` and `pool.startmap` function, which takes a function and a list of iterables as function arguments, and applies the function in a parallel fashion.

Comment: Could you please edit my code suggesting your approach to try it out because I am not familiar with this methodology.. thanks.

Comment: You could parallelize using  https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel.
Since your code is too complicated for me and has some undefined variables at the function scope, e.g. `sp_500`, I couldn't edit it. But have a look at this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56626819/8265036

Comment: Please share a [mcve](/help/mcve). A sample of the original df and the expected output will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the dataframe into parts and execute them concurrently using python's **multiprocessing** module.
You can use multiprocessing.Pool or multiprocessing.Process for this purpose