# Python Threads with Pandas Dataframe does not improve performance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-multithreading

i have a Dataframe of 200k lines, i want to split into parts and call my function S_Function for each partition.

```
def S_Function(df):
    #mycode here 
    return new_df
```

Main program

```
N_Threads = 10
Threads = []
Out = []

size = df.shape[0] // N_Threads

for i in range(N_Threads + 1):

    begin = i * size
    end = min(df.shape[0], (i+1)*size)
    Threads.append(Thread(target = S_Function, args = (df[begin:end])) )
```

I run the threads & make the join :

```
for i in range(N_Threads + 1):
    Threads[i].start()

for i in range(N_Threads + 1):
    Out.append(Threads[i].join())

output = pd.concat(Out)
```

The code is working perfectly but the problem is that using `threading.Thread` did not decrease the execution time.

Sequential Code : 16 minutes
Parallel Code : 15 minutes

Can someone explain what to improve, why this is not working well?

Comment: Do you have to create a whole new DataFrame or have you consider the use of `apply()`. This `pandas` function has multiple ways to be parallelized. One of them is [`pandarallel`](https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel). You can have more information on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784164/pandas-multiprocessing-apply)

Comment: Also, multi-threading is not supposed to speed up the execution, what you need to look into is called multi-processing.

Comment: Do you use `Thread` from `threading` module?

Comment: @Corralien Yes, i mentionned it  at the end  (threading.Thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `threading` when you have to process CPU-bound operations. To achieve your goal, I think you should use `multiprocessing` module

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import time
import functools

# Modify here
CHUNKSIZE = 20000

def S_Function(df, dictionnary):
    # do stuff here
    new_df = df
    return new_df


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Load your dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(1, 30000000, 200000).tolist()})

    # Create chunks to process
    chunks = (df[i:i+CHUNKSIZE] for i in range(0, len(df), CHUNKSIZE))
    dictionnary = {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}
    s_func = functools.partial(S_Function, dictionnary=dictionnary)

    start = time.time()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
        data = pool.map(s_func, chunks)
        out = pd.concat(data)
    end = time.time()

    print(f"Elapsed time: {end - start:.2f} seconds")
```

Comment: I can't wait to see if it improves the calculation time :)

Comment: if i have many parameters in S_Function, how can i do that.

Comment: Use `starmap` instead of `map`. Can you provide the function signature of `S_Function` please?

Comment: `def S_Function(df, dictionnary)`  my program is kind of string matching with cosinus distance and levenstein between rows in df and all the dictionnary

Comment: the `dictionnary` is the same for all the threads, only `df`  changes

Comment: The easiest way is to use `partial` from `functools`.

Comment: I finally did it as a global var, the new execution time is  45 s :)

Comment: The partial function doesn't work?