# BufferError when using multiprocessing in pandas Dataframes with pycharm debugger

Tags: python, pandas, debugging, pycharm, multiprocessing

I am trying to apply a function to each column of a dataframe using multiprocessing.

This was my approach based on [Question 26784164](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784164/pandas-multiprocessing-apply)

```py
    def function_that_takes_df(cls, df: pandas.DataFrame):
        processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 3
        split_data = numpy.array_split(df, processes, axis=1)

        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes) as p:
            data = p.map(run_on_subset, split_data)

        return pandas.concat(data, axis=1)

    def run_on_subset(cls, data_subset) -> pandas.DataFrame:
        x = data_subset.apply(function_that_takes_column)
        return x
```

It works when I run the code, but if I try to debug it in Pycharm, I get:

```
Exception ignored in tp_clear of: <class 'memoryview'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 173, in MakeOleRepr
    olerepr = build.LazyDispatchItem(attr, None)
BufferError: memoryview has 1 exported buffer
```