# automatically delete users who meet criteria

Tags: python, django

I want to use this query-set to automatically delete registered users who did not activate their account : `User.objects.filter(is_active=False).filter(profile__key_expires__lt=timezone.now()).delete()`, but i don't know where to put it.

Views and functions need to be called to execute, but i need this code to run continuously or at least in frequent intervals.

Comment: What about a periodic task using [Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)?

Comment: consider using `celery` for periodic task

Comment: @Filly I'm contemplating using celery as you suggested, do you think it's easier to learn vs cron ?
Please post your previous comment as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Great, I love Celery! I added the comment as an answer and linked to another thread describing the difference between Celery and cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your code in a periodic task using [Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16234656/1924026) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18190019/1924026) threads about differences between crontab scripts and Celery.

Comment: Thanks for differences between cron and celery

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate script and run it in background with `cron`

This is the best way not to overload your Django app. E.g [here my script](https://github.com/d3QUone/ask_kasatkin/blob/master/ask_kasatkin/best_parser.py) that loads best members and popular tags. Check how I've imported Django in it

Comment: Periodic task is a new ground for me, therefore i need a well documented tool. I'm contemplating using celery as suggested by Filly, which one do you think is easier to learn?

Comment: It depends on what you know about Unix systems. Try both :)

Comment: Not much unfortunately, so i guess I'm left with celery as the only choice.
+1 for pointing me to cron (i heard about it before, but never knew or had the time to search what is it for).