# Difference between usage of Django celery and Django cron-jobs?

Tags: django, cron, celery, django-celery, django-cron

I am sorry if its basics but I did not find any answers on the Internet comparing these two technologies. How should I decide when to use which as both can be used to schedule and process periodic tasks.

This is what an article says:

**Django-celery :**

> Jobs are essential part of any application that does
>   some processing for you in the background. If your job is real time
>   Django application celery can be used.

**Django-cronjobs :**

> django-cronjobs  can be used to schedule periodic_task which is a
>   valid job. django-cronjobs is a simple Django app that runs registered
>   cron jobs via a management command.

can anyone explain me the difference between when should I choose which one and Why? Also I need to know why celery is used when the computing is distributed and why not cron jobs

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The two things can be used for the same goal (background execution). However, if you are going to choose wisely, you should really understand that **they are actually completely different things**.

Here's what I wish someone had told me back when I was a noob (instead of the novice level that I have achieved today :)).

**cron**

The concept of a *cron job* is that we want a command / process to be executed on some schedule. Furthermore, we want that process to receive x,y,z parameters, run with a,b,c environment variables, and as user id 123.

Some cron systems may facilitate a few extra features, such as:

- catching up on missed tasks (e.g. the server was off for a power outage all night and as soon as we turn it on, it runs the 8 instances of the command we normally run hourly).
- might help you with the type of locking you normally do using a pid file in order to avoid parallel runs of the same command.

For the most part, cron systems are meant to be **dumb**: "just run this command at this time, thanks!".

**Celery**

The concept of *Celery* is much more sophisticated. It works with tasks, chains & chords of tasks, error handling, and (in most cases) collection of work result. It has a queue (or many queues) of work and a worker (or many). When a task (really just a message describing requested work) enters the queue it waits there until a worker is available to handle it. Much the same way as 1 or more employees at the DMV service a room full of waiting customers.

Furthermore, Celery can facilitate distributed work. That's a bit like (if I may torture the analogy a bit) - the difference between a DMV office where every worker shares the same phone, computer, copier, etc and a DMV where workers have dedicated resources and are never blocked by other workers.

**Celery for web apps**

In web applications, Celery is often used when a bit of web access results in a thing to be done that should be handled out of band of the conversation with the web browser. For example:

- the web user just did something which should result in an email being sent. In order to send an email, your web server will need to contact a mail server. This could take time, the server could be busy, etc - we cant make the web user just wait, seeing nothing on their browser while we do this.  Well, you can but it won't work reliably.  So, we do that email send as a bit of work in the queue. That way, it can happen "whenever" and the web server can get back to communicating with the browser.
- the user just submitted a credit card as payment. You're going to need to contact the card processor, but that might take several seconds. You might even have to contact them multiple times (e.g. they are really busy there right now). Again, you don't want your user's web browser to just sit blankly and you don't want a web server process or thread of execution tied up. Instead, you use Celery to create a job, you tell the browser to check back in a few seconds (or use a "web socket"), and your web server moves on and talks to other web users. When the browser checks back later, you lookup the task id and find out from celery whether it is finished and what the outcome was (card declined, etc).

**Using Celery as cron**

When you use Celery as a "cron system" all you are really doing is saying: "hey, can someone please generate work of X type on Y schedule". A process is created that runs continuously which sleeps most of the time and wakes up occasionally to inject a bit of work into the queue on the schedule you requested.

Usually the "hey someone" that you ask to do that for you is: *celery beat* and *beat* gets the schedule you want from somewhere in the database or from your settings file.

Comment: does celery beat takes care of running the job periodically or at a particular time?

Comment: Yes, to both of those things. See documentation https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: thank you for writing all this. This explanation is so clear and straightforward to understand!!

Comment: Love the humility - hope you've progressed from novice to senior novice =)

Answer (score 2):

I searched for celery vs cron and found a few results that might be helpful to you.

- https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/m2dg8/explain_like_im_five_why_or_why_not_would_celery/
- [Why would running scheduled tasks with Celery be preferable over crontab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187751/why-would-running-scheduled-tasks-with-celery-be-preferable-over-crontab)
- [Distributed task queues (Ex. Celery) vs crontab scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232572/distributed-task-queues-ex-celery-vs-crontab-scripts)

Comment: celery can be used for periodic as well as processing data from messaging queues as and when it arrives. But cron jobs can only be used for periodic task which we need to set at what time the jobs will run periodically. Am I right?

Comment: Correct. You could schedule it to run every minute giving it an appearance of always processing in the background, but then you run into race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to comment on my response.

To manage in demand tasks that can be done in the background. For example, send email with login details after they complete  registration. We can put all email notification tasks in celery.

To manage regular scheduled task, you can use corn job. For example, check and notify all those users who have payment failure by sending email every end of the month.You can create celery tasks to send them.