# Schedule table updates in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

How do you schedule updating the contents of a database table in Django based on time of day. For example every 5 minutes Django will call a REST api to update contents of a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your question, I am not 100% clear what you are looking for. But, assuming you are looking to run some sort of a task every 5 minutes (that will make calls to the DB), then I **highly** suggest you look at [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

It is a robust task schedules, with [specific Django integration](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html). Once you get thru the [getting started](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html) documentation, what you want to look at in particular is called [CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html). This allows you to sort of setup cron like calls.

This has a lot of [benefits over cron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16234656/1036843), and for most use cases I find it to be a better alternative. Scalability is a huge feature for me.

Good luck!

Comment: Celery should work, I just need to test. Thanks a lot!

Comment: FWIW, I also tend to use `redis` as my broker instead of RabbitMQ. I really like redis for a lot of uses, so I usually stick with it here too: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html

Comment: If you like this answer, can you please mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is likely best accomplished by writing a server-side python script and adding a cronjob

Comment: can you give a some detail?

Comment: I probably should have asked before , which platform is hosting the app? (Windows, OSX, Linux?)

Comment: It's hosted on Linux.