# Processing a big file that takes time and fill the ram

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, concurrency, bigdata

I am processing a file that has `10 millions` records that has to be looped among `8 millions records` which will also be looped `150000`,i tried to divide the `150000` into `30000` each but still fills ram of `500GB`, tried multiprocessing but still it fill out my memory.I have been doing this for almost a week still i am ending up `killing all`processes`because they fill my memory,any help would be appreciated. the coding part of`multiprocessing`[is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37907350/apply-async-callback-function-not-being-called)

Comment: What do you mean "has to be looped among 8 million records" and "also be looped 150000"? Do you have a simple example of the approaches that you have tried?

Comment: basically...10 millions of users impressions recommended to different 150000,each users has item recommendation. which are in total 8 millions..for each users i have to get all his recommendation that i got from impressions(10M) .basically there is no way i can get users recommendation without reading all these records in memory..the only slicing that can be possible is to do it in batch of users..even 10thousands users are filling the memory i have!

Comment: That does not clarify much. Is it `10 million` impressions for each of `150000` user, or over all users? Are the impressions of `8 million` different items? What does it mean that each user has item recommendation? What is the format of the data? Are the rows keyed on the impression and include associated user/item? Is it possible to pre-load the items or the users? Please update the original question with clarification.

Comment: Also, please provide more information about your implementation attempts. How are you trying to read and parse the records? Are you trying to read the entire subset into memory at the same time, or are you reading line by line? What do you mean by you have tried multiprocessing?

Comment: when a user log in the website..he is given recommended jobs as list ...each recommendation is user id with item ids...so basically..its 10 millions list..the item vary...in total..they are 8millions different items..so for each user i have to get the item he was recommended...i have 150000 users...yes..i read line by line...my take was to divide users..and process a batch of 30,20,10k as the memory got overfilled over and over...for multiprocessing..i posted the link in the questions that highlight my problem with codes.